# Extracting all reviews of particular app from Google play store website

Tags: selenium-webdriver, python

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys


class FindByXpathCss():

    Reviews = []
    reviewText = []
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"F:\Chrome-webdriver\chromedriver.exe")
    driver.maximize_window()
    baseUrl = "https://play.google.com/store/apps/details? 
    id=com.delta.mobile.android&hl=en_US&showAllReviews=true"
    driver.get(baseUrl)

    driver.find_element_by_tag_name('body').send_keys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN)
    time.sleep(3)

    review_btn = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//button[contains(@class,'')][contains(text(),'Full 
    Review')]")

    for btn in review_btn:
        btn.click()
```

I am able to get only one review even though I have used List type to get all the reviews, please help to print all the reviews. Moreover, its not getting all reviews  (only getting till some reviews)

```
    for textreview in reviewText:
        Reviews.append(textreview.text)
        print(Reviews)

        driver.close()
```

Comment: how are you getting value in reviewtext, add that code ,

Comment: use getAttribute('textContent') instead of getText might fix the issue if you are sure about the logic

Comment: reviewText = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[2]/span[1]")     , 

This is the code I am using to get reviewText of each reviews.

Comment: Still one more issue is there, div tag having 2 span tags, if the review is short one span tag having text, if it crossed some limit, another span having it,..


    for i in range(1, 40):
        if driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@jscontroller='LVJlx'][1]//button")[i].is_enabled():
            reviewFullText = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@jscontroller='LVJlx']//span[2]")
        else:
            reviewFullText = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@jscontroller='LVJlx']//span[1]")

    for reviewText in reviewFullText:
        Reviews.append(reviewText.text)

Answer (score 1):

Below is the code for doing that in java , you can use the same logic in python.

**The logic is:**

1. Get all displayed review, store the length to a variable 'tmp'
2. Scroll to last review
3. Check whether show more is displayed, if displayed then click it
4. Get all reviews again, check whether the current length == 'tmp' , set tmp to new value
5. Continue scrolling to last element and clicking show more, till current length== 'tmp'

   ```
      driver.manage().window().maximize();
          String baseUrl = "https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.delta.mobile.android&hl=en_US&showAllReviews=true";
          driver.get(baseUrl);
          List<WebElement> a;

          //find all the reviews
          a= driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("span[jsname=\"bN97Pc\"]"));
          int b = 0;
          JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
          WebElement showmore;

          //scroll to last element
          while(a.size()!=b) {

              b=a.size();
              System.out.println("size of b is "+ b); 
              js.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();",  a.get(a.size() - 1));
              Thread.sleep(3000);

              Boolean isPresent = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[contains(text(),\"Show More\")]/../..")).size() > 0;

              if(isPresent) {
                  showmore= driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[contains(text(),\"Show More\")]/../.."));
                  showmore.click();
                  Thread.sleep(2000);
              }

              a= driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("span[jsname=\"bN97Pc\"]"));
              System.out.println("size of b is "+ a.size());
              System.out.println(a.size()== b); 
          }

          for (WebElement review : a) {
               System.out.println(review.getText()); 
           }
   ```

Comment: Still one more issue is there, div tag having 2 span tags, if the review is short one span tag having text, if it crossed some limit, another span having it,..

    for i in range(1, 40):
        if driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@jscontroller='LVJlx'][1]//button")[i].is_enabled():
            reviewFullText = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@jscontroller='LVJlx']//span[2]")
        else:
            reviewFullText = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@jscontroller='LVJlx']//span[1]")

    for reviewText in reviewFullText:
        Reviews.append(reviewText.text)